# Hibernate update with partitionkey in join column

Tags: jpa, spring-data, hibernate-6.x

I have below two entities

**Contact**:

```
@Table(name = "contacts")
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamicUpdate
public class SalesContact
    implements Serializable {
@Column(name = "created_at")
@CreatedDate
private Instant createdAt;

@Column(name = "updated_at")
private Instant updatedAt;

@PartitionKey
@Column(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
private Long accountId;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "contact", orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<ContactEmail> emails;

public void setEmails(Set<ContactEmail> emails){
    this.emails = new HashSet<>();
    for (ContactEmail email : emails) {
        email.setContact(this);
    }
    this.emails.addAll(emails);
}}
```

**ContactEmail**:

```
@Table(name = "contact_emails")
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Getter
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ContactEmail {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "created_at")
@CreatedDate
private Instant createdAt;

@Column(name = "updated_at")
@LastModifiedDate
private Instant updatedAt;


@Column(name = "email")
private String email;


@ManyToOne
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "account_id", nullable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
@Setter
@JsonBackReference
private SalesContact contact;
}
```

When we try to update the contact, via below snippet hibernate incorrectly generates the update query.

```
 SalesContact salesContact = salesContactRepository.findByIdAndAccountId(id, 1679911196L).get();
    salesContact.setFirstName("demo-2x");
    SalesContact saved = salesContactRepository.save(salesContact);
```

**Query generated**:

update contacts set first_name=? where id=? and account_id=? and account_id=?

**Exception**:

2023-06-26T15:37:09.802+05:30 ERROR 18627 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement [No value specified for parameter 4] [update contacts set first_name=? where id=? and account_id=? and account_id=?]; SQL [update contacts set first_name=? where id=? and account_id=? and account_id=?]] with root cause

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your settings and got the same error. I'm using Spring Boot 3.1.0 and Hibernate 6.2.2.Final

My code:

```
customer = customerRepository.findByIdAndName(id, oldName).get();
customer.setEmail(newEmail);
Customer saved = customerRepository.save(customer);
```

Generated SQL:

```
Hibernate: update customer set email=?,name=? where id=? and name=? and name=?
```

Error:

```
Parameter "#5" is not set;
```

**Solution**

The ManyToOne relationship is not correct configured with two join columns. The only ID annotated for Hibernate is the Id field. This should be the only one join column.

Wrong:

```
@ManyToOne
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_name", referencedColumnName = "name", nullable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private Customer customer;
```

Correct:

```
@ManyToOne
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private Customer customer;
```

With the above code the update SQL is correct and the error is gone:

```
Hibernate: update customer set email=?,name=? where id=? and name=?
```

Comment: Unfortunately i need to use both the join columns in my usecase. i need to add account_id / contact_id for the join condition.

Comment: Then you should consider defining this columns as a composite id (primary key) of the table contacts. Partition key is not the same. It will be added by Hibernate to the update clause for better performance.

Comment: Problem with composite key is hibernate does not return the generate value when part of the composite key is generated.

Comment: It is only true for Embeddable. But you can model composite key with IdClass and use GeneratedValue. Check here for details https://thorben-janssen.com/composite-primary-keys-sequence/#Mapping_an_IdClass

Comment: With IdClass, we get below exception

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field org.hibernate.bugs.JPAUnitTestCaseIdClass$CompositeKey.id to org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$2

Comment: Did you precisely follow the guide from the above link? We can't help you without seeing the modified code of entities. Consider adding a new question for the problem with IdClass. I think the current question about partition key in join column has been answered.